# React Native - make dummy db get real data from api

Tags: json, typescript, react-native, fetch-api

I am quite new to React Native and JS and have recently purchased a React Native template which has a Dummy DB.

Ideally Id like it to pull data from an external JSON (API) which is being generated from a PHP website we already have running.

Here is the Dummy data file:

```
import {
  DoctorModel,
  TreatmentModel,
  CampaignModel,
  EventModel
} from "../models";

export const doctorsList: DoctorModel[] = [ { ##JSON HERE## } ];

export const treatmentsList: TreatmentModel[] = [ { ##JSON HERE## } ];

export const campaignList: CampaignModel[] = [ { ##JSON HERE## } ];

export const eventList: EventModel[] = [ { ##JSON HERE## } ];
```

I want it to export as the same values as above so it will work seamlessly with the current app configuration.

I have tried the following...

```
export const doctorsList: DoctorModel[] = () =>
  fetch(' ##LINK TO API## ')
    .then((response) => response.json());
```

But got this error:

```
Type '() => Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'DoctorModel[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.
```

I have looked all over here and other platforms for a solution but cant find anything.

Again the ideal outcome would for it to work exactly how it would if I manually typed the JSON in as seen in the first code snippet.

Any help is much appreciated, still trying to wrap my head around React! :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t look like a react problem, but a typescript one. Typescript does a type inference from your return value to check and see if it matches what you’ve stated.

In short: you’ve just declared your types wrong.

The function doesn’t return a `DoctorModel[]` it’s returning `Promise<DoctorModel[]>`

```
export const doctorsList: Promise<DoctorModel[]> = () =>
  fetch(' ##LINK TO API## ')
    .then((response) => response.json() as DoctorsModel[]);
```

So changing that line ought to make your typescript compiler chooch again!

Comment: Type '() => Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<DoctorModel[]>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally

Comment: Type 'Promise<DoctorModel[]>' is not an array type.

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your help but it still says: Type '() => Promise<DoctorModel[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<DoctorModel[]>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally